# Быстрая печать html кода

Tags: html5

Видел как некоторые пишут всякие команды по типу ntw-fdskl-fdsafl и у них генерируется готовые блоки с кодом и классами, что это за команды, есть ли они в vscode и если нету то какое расширение нужно устанавливать?

Answer (score 1):

Расширение называется `Emmet` почитайте о нём

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте расширение emmet (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet).

Comment: @khalinmaxim: опередил!))

Comment: есть такое немножко)

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нравится такой подход, можете также присмотреться к [Pug](https://pugjs.org/language/tags.html), чтобы использовать сокращённый синтаксис **вместо** html (хотя такое решение подойдёт только если проект целиком в ваших руках).